# solving recurrence by substitution, calculations doesnt add up

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

I have this recurence p(n) = 2p(n-2) + n, and I have guessed that the solution is O(n^2), however, when I do the following calculations, I cannot get the inequality to hold

p(n-2) <= c*(n-2)² (induction hypothesis)

2(c*(n-2)²) + n <= cn² (substitution)

cn²-8c + n <= cn²

Can anyone see where I go wrong? I also tried for even larger O(n^x) but i still doesnt work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths (try http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: this is part of the CS curriculum so i though it would be fine

Comment: It's CS maths, which is why you should ask at the CS stack-exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is because it is NOT `O(n^2)`, In fact, this is `Omega(2^(n/2))`

```
p(n) = 2p(n-2) + n = 2(2(p(n-4) + n-2) + n = 
     = 2(2(2(p(n-6) + n-4) + n-2) + n = .... =
     = 2^(n/2) * 1 + 2^(n/2-1) * 3 + ... + 2^1 (n-2) + 2^0 * n
```

From the above you can see that the recurrence is NOT `O(n^2)`, since the very first element in the sum is 2^(n/2), which is much larger than O(n^2) for sufficiently large values of `n`.

Since it seems like homework, I'd rather let you try and solve it on your own from here, after the initial mistake is clear.

Good luck!